# Get previously caught exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

Is it possible to get the `Exception` that was previously caught by some library in Python 2.7? The library does something like this:

```
try:
    something_that_throw_exception
except Exception, e:
    raise Exception("Error", e)
```

and I would like to get the type or instance of `e`.

Comment: Well how are you then catching the re-raised error? If you're doing the same thing (i.e. `except Exception, e:` - although note that `Exception as e` is more modern) then the original exception is `e.args[1]`.

Comment: Hm.. it seems `e.args[1]` solves my problem, thx.